# Is there any way to kill a setInterval loop through an Onclick button

Tags: javascript, onclick, infinite-loop, setinterval

So, I got an infinite loop to work in this function using setInterval attached to an onClick. Problem is, I can't stop it using clearInterval in an onClick. I think this is because when I attach a clearInterval to an onClick, it kills a specific interval and not the function altogether. Is there anything I can do to *kill all intervals* through an onClick?

Here's my [.js file](http://lucas.cis.temple.edu/~c10520124/lab6/gol.js) and the calls I'm making are

```
input type="button" value="generate" onClick="generation();

input type="button" value="Infinite Loop!" onclick="setInterval('generation()',1000);"

input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearInterval(generation(),80;" // This one here is giving me trouble.
```

Answer (score 22):

setInterval returns a handle, you need that handle so you can clear it

easiest, create a var for the handle in your html head, then in your onclick use the var

```
// in the head
var intervalHandle = null;

// in the onclick to set
intervalHandle = setInterval(....

// in the onclick to clear
clearInterval(intervalHandle);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: It's not working for me :( says the interval ID is null

Answer (score 4):

`clearInterval` is applied on the return value of `setInterval`, like this:

```
var interval = null;
theSecondButton.onclick = function() {
    if (interval === null) {
       interval = setInterval(generation, 1000);
    }
}
theThirdButton.onclick = function () {
   if (interval !== null) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       interval = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: if (interval === null) should be if (interval !== null)

Comment: @Hatim: Fixed .

Answer (score -1):

Have `generation();` call `setTimeout` to itself instead of `setInterval`. That was you can use a bit if logic in the function to prevent it from running `setTimeout` quite easily.

```
var genTimer
var stopGen = 0

function generation() {
   clearTimeout(genTimer)  ///stop additional clicks from initiating more timers
   . . .
   if(!stopGen) {
       genTimer = setTimeout(function(){generation()},1000)
   }
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question of "Is there any way to kill a setInterval loop through an Onclick button"