# Javascript ID reassignment

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project, and I want to make 4 images move in a circular fashion once I click on one of them. This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to make the circle keep going. Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Lab 13B </title>
<style>
    #pic1 {
        padding-left:325px;
    }
    #pic2 {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
    #pic3 {
        padding-left: 350px;
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
    #pic4 {
        padding-left: 325px;
        padding-top: 120px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function one() {
        document.getElementById("pic1").src = "water.PNG";
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "fire.PNG";
        document.getElementById("pic3").src = "Air.PNG";
        document.getElementById("pic4").src = "earth.PNG";
        document.getElementById("pic1").id = "pic2";
        document.getElementById("pic2").id = "pic4";
        document.getElementById("pic3").id = "pic1";
        document.getElementById("pic4").id = "pic3";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src = "Air.PNG" alt="air" width="300px" height="300px" id="pic1" onclick="one()";> <br>
    <img src = "water.PNG" alt="water" width="300px" height="300px" id="pic2" onclick="one()";> 
    <img src = "earth.PNG" alt="earth" width="300px" height="300px" id='pic3' onclick="one()";> <br>
    <img src = "fire.PNG" alt="fire" width="300px" height="300px" id='pic4' onclick="one()";> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should probably try a while loop and rather than changing the id change the image src on each iteration. Even better would be to set the image as a background, defined as a css class and apply the class on iteration.

Comment: What do you mean "move in a circular fashion"?

Comment: Why would you change their `id` instead of their `src` (if you're committed to moving them this way instead of using css transitions and positions)?

Comment: or apply/remove CSS classes?

Comment: It seems a very bad idea to change the `id`s, especially the way you do it. E.g. you change pic1 to have id="pic2" - okay, that might work, but what should be the result of the next statement, which tries to find the **image with id="pic2" of which there are now 2** (the original one + the one you just changed)? Element ids in HTML *must* always be unique, and you are violating that rule on the first `id` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially talking about an animation where you need to change something around after specific time interval.

To achieve things like that Javascript provides `setInterval` function where you can run a piece of code responsible for "change" after given interval in milliseconds. So your function `one` will look something like

```
function one() {
  setInterval(function() {
    // your logic for swapping src of images
  }, 1000)
}
```

But this will require you to properly handle click event, first click will start the animation but second will create the interval again and so on, so considering this if you already have interval running then on second click you might want to stop the animation or at least prevent the creation of second interval. This might be of some help [Is there any way to kill a setInterval loop through an Onclick button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790815/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-setinterval-loop-through-an-onclick-button)

Comment: I don't want to switch it after an interval, I want to switch it onmouseover. I am only swapping picture order around